# c# TcpSocket speed depends on connection to client?

Tags: c#, performance, stream

I've got a client-server application which is communicating via an SslStream.
If I run the client inside the same network as the server is in, the speed for sending some data is about **130ms**. But when the client is running at a different machine outside the network, sending the same data is about **1046ms**.
I always thought that sending via a stream only sends the bytes as fast as it can, independent if the connection goes out of the network, or the clients download speed. So do I think here wrong, or could this happen by a different issue?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: "sends the bytes as fast as it can" - yes, yes it does. How fast it can send the data *depends* on the bandwidth and latency of each network link that the data has to traverse.

Comment: So does this mean that if I **SslStream.Write(byte[])**, internally the Stream waits for all bytes have been sended and a response from the client is received?
Or maybe for every packet must be a response received?

Comment: It depends - there's a certain amount of buffering on the sending side, and `SslStream.Write(...);` won't return until all of the data that you're sending has either actually been sent or is at least inside those buffers (rather than it relying upon being able to access data still within the original `byte[]`) after the call returns.

Comment: does "has actually been sent" mean that sending is finished after the client received the bytes?